# Python - IOError while writing a formatted string

Tags: python, logging, ioerror

I get this exception while using my `logger` function. I do not get why it tries to *open* my log content.

This is my code which throws the `IOError` exception:

```
try:
    logger(paths['log'], "Renamed %s in %s." % (song.getPath(), song.getTag('title')))
except IOError as err:
    logger(paths['log'], "IOError: %s" % err)
```

and this is my `logger` function:

```
def logger(log_path, log_content):
    """
    :param log_path: where the log is going to be written
    :param log_content: what to write
    """

    log = open(log_path + "/" + "pynderella.log", 'a')
    log.write("%s: %s\n" % (time.strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S"), log_content))
    log.close()
```

Exception output **(the non existent file is part of the "log_content" argument [in this case, *song.getPath()*!)**:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path/to/a/file/file.ext'
```

**NOTE THAT THE EXCEPTION IS LOGGED PROPERLY!**

**EDIT:**

getPath():

```
    def getPath(self):
    return self.path
```

**init**() of the Song class:

```
    def __init__(self, path):
    """
    :param path: the path of the song
    """
    self.path = os.path.abspath(path)
```

getTag():

```
def getTag(self, tag):
    """
    Returns a tag from the song.
    :param tag: which tag wants to be retrieved
    """
    track = None
    if getExtension(self.path) in ['.mp3', '.mpeg3']:
        track = EasyID3(self.path)
    elif getExtension(self.path) == '.mp4':
        track = EasyMP4(self.path)

    try:
        if tag.lower() in ['title', 'artist', 'album']:
            return track[tag][0].encode('ascii', 'ignore')  # it was encoded in unicode
    except Exception as err:
        logger(paths['log'], "Exception getTag: %s" % err)
        return None
```

EDIT 2:
This is my log file output:

```
21-03-14 16:27:16: Moved /Users/user/pynderella/daemon/source/boh.mp3 in destination/Paramore/All We Know Is Falling.

21-03-14 16:27:16: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'destination/Paramore/All We Know Is Falling/boh.mp3'
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the entire code of your logger function, to me it looks like you're not closing the file. Then the file handle is busy and you can't open it for another log append.

Even if this turns out not to be the cause of the problem, might be worth to use try with resources (or try-finally) in your logger function to ensure releasing the handle on the file.

Comment: Added the log.close() directive (nice catch!) but the exception is still thrown.

Comment: I think, though, that the problem is in the way I pass it a string with two arguments in its formatting "section". In the "exception log" I pass only one "formatting string".

Comment: Note that if there is some failure during writing to file, your log.close() in consecutive line won't be executed.

Comment: Should I throw another exception? (I tried to re-execute my application and the exception is still the same, though)

Comment: Ok, just for debug, try entering a simple "test string" into the file. If this works ok, means there's a problem with how you use the method. If it still fails, it's filesystem or file handling issue. Either way you'll know a bit more.

Comment: The thing is that the logger in the Exception works while the "try" logger doesn't. Furthermore I noticed that the logger does not find the "song.getPath()" file which it DOES NOT NEED to be opened! I just need to print that path to the log file!

Comment: I run your code. Assuming your song.getPath() and song.getTag() correctly return string, it works. I think your problem is in implementation of the song class, and exception there propagates to your logger. If your getPath() is like java's File.getPath, then it does need the song to be an opened file.

Comment: Edited my description! I added the functions source code.

Comment: In your getTag() you're calling logger and there you're calling getTag(). You initialize song and the abspath() doesn't check if the file actualy exists. If it does not, then getTag throws IOException, which is caught by general Exception catch, but that calls getTag() again. It's a bit of a pretzel methinks. :)

Comment: What do you suggest to do to clean up my code? Throw in some specific exception in every function of my class and removing the "automatic" logging function in every of them?

Comment: Could you please post a possible fix?

Comment: Actually I have to withdraw my previous comment. Logger itself doesn't call getTag, which is good. It's also good that you log all errors. I would check for file existence in the __init__, and not allow for object to be created if path is invalid. Maybe raise exception? This will prevent your file not found issue on when you try to manipulate the object.
(sorry, not in my office right now. cant type well from tablet)

Comment: I see you found that the media file is not found. Does it get copied successfully to destination? Are you using shutil.copyfile(file,newpath)?

Comment: The application works with no problems at all but I've that message spammed every time. I use shutil.move.

Comment: Ok, good. Shutil is implemented to be locking (I assume you're not using multithreading/mulitprocessing). Also it creates destination folder if it doesn't already exist. That makes it interesting that you still get an exception that the file is missing right after it was moved. It's looking for the file at relative path - double-check if "destination/Paramore/All We Know Is Falling/boh.mp3" is valid. Look at your stack trace to see exactly which call throws it or maybe add a os.path.isfile() right after the move.

Comment: You can check the entire source at https://github.com/krishath/pynderella . I'll let you know if that works. Thanks for your help!